# Create new list field type for EasyAdmin

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

With EasyAdmin Symfony bundle, with Symfony 4.2, how create a new list field type?

**Use case**

"I want to display a link to show page in the list table"

(not a form type, a list type):

```
easy_admin:
  entities:
    offer:
      class: App\Entity\Offer
      list:
        fields:
          - { property: name, type: MY_TYPE??? }
```

Comment: create a field type for a list view, I cant say more than that :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 solutions i believe :

1. If the url is stored in your object there is a custom type for this :
   https://symfony.com/doc/2.x/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/list-search-show-configuration.html#url-data-type

It allows you to display an url :

```
# config/packages/easy_admin.yaml
easy_admin:
    entities:
        Product:
            class: App\Entity\User
            list:
                fields:
                    - { property: 'blogUrl', type: 'url' }
```

2. If you don't have the full url you can try by using a custom template :
   https://symfony.com/doc/2.x/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/tutorials/custom-property-options.html#custom-property-options

This way you can define a custom template to generate your url and pass a param if you need :

```
# config/packages/easy_admin.yaml
easy_admin:
    entities:
        Product:
            class: App\Entity\Product
            list:
                fields:
                    # ...
                    - { property: 'tags', template: 'admin/tag_collection.html.twig',
                        label_colors: ['primary', 'success', 'info'] }
```

Comment: template option is perfect! I should have full read the doc first :/ thanks you.

Comment: the link is broken now ... probably this: https://symfony.com/doc/2.x/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/tutorials/custom-property-options.html#custom-property-options